# Set constructor values without passing them values

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to set my setCell method but i have not been provided the values in the parameters in the testing file. **this should print me a box with 20 rows and 30 columns using the '*' char** but it is printing blank lines for me

```
    public Window(final int rows, final int cols, final char border)
   {
         //Initialize everything
         this.rows = rows;
         this.cols = cols;
         this.border = border;
         this.shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
         this.cells = new char[rows+2][cols+2];
         //Make a call to addBorders()
         addBorders(border);
   }

void setCell(final int row, final int col, final char ch)
   {
         //set the character at cells[row][col] to 'ch'
         cells[row][col]=ch;

   }


public void display()
   {
      for (int i=0; i < rows+2; i++)
      {
         for(int j=0; j<cols+2; j++)
            System.out.print(cells[i][j]);
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
```

And my tester file is =>

```
public class HouseForSale
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        //Create the window
        Window w = new Window(20, 30, '*');
        w.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You have posted your code, but you haven't told us what the problem with it is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call setrCell in your Constructor function( Window ). like below:

```
public Window(final int rows, final int cols, final char border)
   {
         //Initialize everything
         this.rows = rows;
         this.cols = cols;
         this.border = border;
         this.shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
         this.cells = new char[rows+2][cols+2];

         for (int i=0; i < rows; i++)
            for(int j=0; j < cols; j++)
               setCell(i,j,ch);
         //Make a call to addBorders()
         addBorders(border);
}
```